# Error using russian letters for appendix counter with hyperref and subfig

Tags: hyperref, errors, subfloats

I'm preparing a text in russian with `pdflatex`. According to standard appendices must be numbered with russian uppercase letters.

But I've found that if subfloats used in appedix, the `hyperref` produces error on second `pdflatex` pass.

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> subfigure.\T 
                        2A\CYRA .1.1
```

Here is code to reproduce the error:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[config,font=small,labelsep=period]{caption,subfig}
\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}

%use russian alphabet for subfigure counter 
\makeatletter
  \def\thesubfigure{\textit{\asbuk{subfigure}}}
  \providecommand\thefigsubsep{,~}
  \def\p@subfigure{\@nameuse{thefigure}\thefigsubsep}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{Sample Chapter}

\appendix
%use russian alphabet for appendix counter
\makeatletter
  \gdef\thechapter{\@Asbuk\c@chapter}
\makeatother

\chapter{Sample Appendix}

Reference \ref{fig_images}, also \ref{fig_image1} and \ref{fig_image2}.

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \subfloat[][]{\label{fig_image1}\includegraphics[width=0.15\linewidth]{image1}}
  \hspace{0.15\linewidth}
  \subfloat[][]{\label{fig_image2}\includegraphics[width=0.15\linewidth]{image2}}
  \caption[]{\label{fig_images}
    Images:
    \subref{fig_image1}~---~first;
    \subref{fig_image2}~---~second;
  }
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Is there any workaround to make it works? Or maybe any alternatives for `subfig` package?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `subfig` package is known to have problems with `hyperref`. You could give my `subcaption` package a try instead:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[config,font=small,labelsep=period]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}

%use russian alphabet for subfigure counter 
\makeatletter
  \def\thesubfigure{\textit{\asbuk{subfigure}}}
  \providecommand\thefigsubsep{,~}
  \def\p@subfigure{\@nameuse{thefigure}\thefigsubsep}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{Sample Chapter}

\appendix
%use russian alphabet for appendix counter
\makeatletter
  \gdef\thechapter{\@Asbuk\c@chapter}
\makeatother

\chapter{Sample Appendix}

Reference \ref{fig_images}, also \ref{fig_image1} and \ref{fig_image2}.

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \subcaptionbox{\label{fig_image1}}{\includegraphics[width=0.15\linewidth]{image1}}
  \hspace{0.15\linewidth}
  \subcaptionbox{\label{fig_image2}}{\includegraphics[width=0.15\linewidth]{image2}}
  \caption[]{\label{fig_images}
    Images:
    \subref{fig_image1}~---~first;
    \subref{fig_image2}~---~second;
  }
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

(I'm sorry for the shameless self-advertisement, but the problems of subfig with hyperref were one of the many reasons why I wrote the subcaption package.)

Addendum:

As opposite to the subfig package the subcaption package will only typeout the value of `\thesubfigure` resp. `\thesubtable` as reference since this is the behaviour of all other references as well, e.g. references to figures or sections. So if one want to have the parenthesis (or other decorative elements) in references, one have to add them there and remove them from the label format (so they will not appear twice there), e.g. by using the option `labelformat=simple`. For example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[config,font=small,labelsep=period]{caption}
\usepackage[labelformat=simple]{subcaption}
\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}

%use russian alphabet for subfigure counter 
\makeatletter
  \def\thesubfigure{(\textit{\asbuk{subfigure}})}
  \providecommand\thefigsubsep{,~}
  \def\p@subfigure{\@nameuse{thefigure}\thefigsubsep}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{Sample Chapter}

\appendix
%use russian alphabet for appendix counter
\makeatletter
  \gdef\thechapter{\@Asbuk\c@chapter}
\makeatother

\chapter{Sample Appendix}

Reference \ref{fig_images}, also \ref{fig_image1} and \ref{fig_image2}.

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \subcaptionbox{\label{fig_image1}}{\includegraphics[width=0.15\linewidth]{image1}}
  \hspace{0.15\linewidth}
  \subcaptionbox{\label{fig_image2}}{\includegraphics[width=0.15\linewidth]{image2}}
  \caption[]{\label{fig_images}
    Images:
    \subref{fig_image1}~---~first;
    \subref{fig_image2}~---~second;
  }
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

2nd Addendum (updated on 2011/08/19):

The `subcaption` package does support different look & feel for references and sub-references since version 1.1 from 2011/08/18, using the new option "subrefformat=". For example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[config,font=small,labelsep=period]{caption}
\usepackage[subrefformat=parens]{subcaption}
\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}

%use russian alphabet for subfigure counter 
\makeatletter
  \def\thesubfigure{\textit{\asbuk{subfigure}}}
  \providecommand\thefigsubsep{,~}
  \def\p@subfigure{\@nameuse{thefigure}\thefigsubsep}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{Sample Chapter}

\appendix
%use russian alphabet for appendix counter
\makeatletter
  \gdef\thechapter{\@Asbuk\c@chapter}
\makeatother

\chapter{Sample Appendix}

Reference \ref{fig_images}, also \ref{fig_image1} and \ref{fig_image2}.

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \subcaptionbox{\label{fig_image1}}{\includegraphics[width=0.15\linewidth]{image1}}
  \hspace{0.15\linewidth}
  \subcaptionbox{\label{fig_image2}}{\includegraphics[width=0.15\linewidth]{image2}}
  \caption[]{\label{fig_images}
    Images:
    \subref{fig_image1}~---~first;
    \subref*{fig_image2}~---~second;
  }
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks Axel! Your solution looks good.Just one small thing, how can to make subrefs to be included in parenthesis? E.g. (a) - first, instead a - first.

Comment: As opposite to the subfig package the subcaption package always gives you `\thesubfigure` resp. `\thesubtable` as reference. So if you want the parenthesis in your references, too, one have to add them there and to remove them from the caption label so they will not appear twice in the figure. In detail one have to load the subcaption package with the option `labelsep=simple` and to add the parenthesis to `\thesubfigure`. I will add this as 2nd solution right now.

Comment: Just added an addendum to my answer.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, your second solution do the trick for `\subref`, but it also it leads to parenthesis in `\ref` output, e.g. `\ref{fig_image1}` outputs `A.1, (a)`, but `A.1, a` expected.

Comment: So the reference should look different for `\ref` and `\subref`? Unfortunately the subcaption package does not support it yet because no-one has asked for such feature yet. Will add it to the very next version... Until then, someone needs to patch `\subref` for himself. Will add an example as 2nd addendum right now...

Comment: Thank you very much Axel! This version works as expected.

Comment: subcaption v1.1 is available on CTAN right now (and hopefully soon as TeXlive and MikTeX update). It supports the option `subrefformat=...`, so patching `\subref` is not necessary anymore. Will update my answer right now... (Furthermore I have extended the `subcaption` package documentation regarding references.)

Comment: I can not compile example in the 2nd Addendum.
Errors:
! Undefined control sequence.
\thechapter -&gt;\@Asbuk 
                      \c@chapter 
l.27 \chapter{Sample Appendix}

Comment: @akj Try removing the code line `\gdef\thechapter{\@Asbuk\c@chapter}`