# custom sub-caption and refs format for subfigures

Tags: floats, cross-referencing, captions, subfloats, subcaption

I've just read questions:

- [Changing the subfigure caption by removing brackets & font of the subcaption](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61612/changing-the-subfigure-caption-by-removing-brackets-font-of-the-subcaption)
- [Adding parentheses around subfig references](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16291/adding-parentheses-around-subfig-references/16292#16292)
- [How to put two images next to each other with a) and b) labels?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25644/subcaption-how-to-redefine-default-separator-between-figure-and-subfigure-numbe)
- [subcaption: how to redefine default separator between figure and subfigure number in \ref's?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25644/subcaption-how-to-redefine-default-separator-between-figure-and-subfigure-numbe)

But i still haven't found answer.

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
 \centering
  \subfloat[subfigure A]{\rule{100pt}{50pt}
   \label{fig:subfig-a}
  }
  \subfloat[subfigure B]{\rule{100pt}{50pt}
   \label{fig:subfig-b}
  }
  \subfloat[subfigure C]{\rule{100pt}{50pt}
   \label{fig:subfig-c}
  }
 \caption{Subfigures:}
 \label{fig:figures}
\end{figure}

See Figures~\ref{fig:subfig-a}, \ref{fig:subfig-b} and~\ref{fig:subfig-c}.
\end{document}
```

Output looks like:
[image: default captions]

What i need:

1. Subcaptions should be `a)`, `b)`, `c)` without caption text instead of `(a)`, `(b)` and `(c)` with caption text.
2. Refs to subfigures should be `1,\,a` instead `1a`.
3. Figure caption should consist of prefix (`Fig.~1.`), separation space, general caption (`Subfigures:`) and sub-captions of subfigures (for example, `(a) --- subfigure A; (b) --- subfigure B; (c) --- subfigure C`).

What i tried:

Set caption

```
\captionsetup[figure]{labelsep=period,justification=centering,singlelinecheck=off}
```

Set ref format

```
\makeatletter
\def\thesubfigure{\textit{\alph{subfigure}}}
\providecommand\thefigsubsep{,\,}
\def\p@subfigure{\@nameuse{thefigure}\thefigsubsep}
\makeatother
```

So i've got:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\captionsetup[figure]{labelsep=period,justification=centering,singlelinecheck=off}

\makeatletter
\def\thesubfigure{\textit{\alph{subfigure}}}
\providecommand\thefigsubsep{,\,}
\def\p@subfigure{\@nameuse{thefigure}\thefigsubsep}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
 \centering
  \subfloat[subfigure A]{\rule{100pt}{50pt}
   \label{fig:subfig-a}
  }
  \subfloat[subfigure B]{\rule{100pt}{50pt}
   \label{fig:subfig-b}
  }
  \subfloat[subfigure C]{\rule{100pt}{50pt}
   \label{fig:subfig-c}
  }
 \caption{Subfigures:}
 \label{fig:figures}
\end{figure}

See Figures~\ref{fig:subfig-a}, \ref{fig:subfig-b} and~\ref{fig:subfig-c}.
\end{document}
```

It looks like that:
[image: custom captions]

It is still needed to correct format of sub-captions and main caption.

Also, why there are different spaces between subfigures?

Answer (score 4):

I don't think using three different formats for the numbering of subfigures is good. Anyway, here it is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelsep=period,justification=centering,singlelinecheck=off}
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{rightparen}{#2)}
\usepackage{subfig}
\captionsetup[subfloat]{labelformat=rightparen}
\showcaptionsetup[uniq]{subfloat}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \g_akj_subfloat_seq
\NewDocumentCommand{\xsubfloat}{ m m }
 {
  \akj_subfloat:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\makexcaption}{o}
 {
  \caption{\IfNoValueF{#1}{#1~}Subfigures:~%
  \seq_use:Nnnn \g_akj_subfloat_seq {;~} {;~} {;~}}
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \akj_subfloat:nn #1 #2
 {
  % initialize
  \int_compare:nT { \value{subfigure} = 0 }
   { \seq_gclear:N \g_akj_subfloat_seq }
  % do the subfloat
  \subfloat[]{#2}
  % store the subcaption
  \seq_gput_right:Nx \g_akj_subfloat_seq { (\exp_not:N\textit{\alph{subfigure}}) ~ \exp_not:n { #1 } }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{\textit{\alph{subfigure}}}
\makeatletter
\def\p@subfigure{\thefigure\,}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\xsubfloat{subfigure A}{%
  \rule{100pt}{50pt}%
  \label{fig:subfig-a}%
}
\xsubfloat{subfigure B}{%
  \rule{100pt}{50pt}%
  \label{fig:subfig-b}%
}
\xsubfloat{subfigure C}{%
  \rule{100pt}{50pt}%
  \label{fig:subfig-c}%
}
\makexcaption\label{fig:figures}
\end{figure}

See Figures~\ref{fig:subfig-a}, \ref{fig:subfig-b} and~\ref{fig:subfig-c}.
\end{document}
```

The `\makexcaption` command has also an optional argument for text going before the list of subcaptions, so

```
\makexcaption[Some text.]
```

would produce

> Figure 1. Some text. Subfigures: (*a*) subfigure A; (*b*) subfigure B; (*c*) subfigure C

Beware of unprotected end-of-lines in the arguments of `\subfloat`, that are the cause of your spurious spaces.

[image]

Comment: I have just tried the code, written by @egreg. My pdfLaTeX (3.1415926-1.40.10) report some errors, for example
`! Undefined control sequence.`
`\akj_subfloat:nn #1#2-&gt;\int_compare:nT` 
`{\value{subfigure}=0}{\seq_gclear:N ...`
`l.43 }`

Comment: @akj Update your TeX distribution; you surely have an old version of `expl3`

Comment: So, i tried to compile eample with pdfTeX(3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13, LaTeX2e 2011/06/27). It also reports errors: `! Undefined control sequence.` `<argument> ...ome text }Subfigures: \seq_use:Nnnn` `\g_akj_subfloat_seq {; }{;...` `l.53 \makexcaption[Some text]` `\label{fig:figures}`. Did i need even newer version (texlive 2013)? Also, there are other errors like `! Undefined control sequence.` `<argument> \LaTeX3 error:` `A sequence was misused.` `l.53 \makexcaption[Some text]` `\label{fig:figures}`

Comment: Also, writelatex.com compiled example well.

Comment: @akj TeX Live 2011 is really too old.

Comment: Okay. I'll try packages from Debian Sid.