# Change ref format for subfigures

Tags: cross-referencing, captions, subcaption

I am using the `caption`and `subcaption` package with `floatrow` and would like to change how references with `\ref` are formated.

First here is my captionsetup so far:

```
\DeclareCaptionSubType[alph]{figure}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=brace,justification=centerlast}
\captionsetup{subrefformat=brace}
```

What I would like to achieve is the following (all for subfigures):

1. the label should be `\alph)`, e.g. a)
2. a `\subref{subfigureLabel}` or `\ref{subfigureLabel}` should return basically the label: `\alph)`, e.g. a)
3. a `\ref{compositeFigure}` should return the prefix, the figurenumber, a space, followed by the label (including the brace), e.g. 'Figure 1.1 a)', (basically append the label of the subfigure with a space).

As you can see I solved (not quite satisfactory) 1. and 2., however I am struggling with three. First of I could not find anything like `refformat`, however there are [good reasons](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25671/19326) for the existence of `subrefformat`. However I want to use `\subref` just for the short version (see 2.), so I can't use that. Furthermore I would like to know if there is an option to set the `label` and `subref` format with one command (I think it is reasonable and common to define them equally).

P.S.: I have seen https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/122306/19326, however it is a) for subfig and b) looks messier/more complicated than what I hope for but if that is what it takes...

Comment: Maybe  [`cleveref`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/cleveref) is worth a look.

Comment: I am not sure yet. Note that I noticed two mistakes in my question and fixed them (I actually want to just `ref` and decide based on the label). The clevermanual states `Cleveref does not modify the standard \ref or \pageref commands`, so I am not sure it is the right tool for the job. I will give it a detailed look in the next day(s) and come back to this.

Comment: You just use `\cref` instead of `\ref`. This command will the decide for you based on the label what it will typeset. However it will not typeset the `)` brace, because this should be used as a delimiter only. If you really need the brace you should just simply redefine `\thesubfigure`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure if this is the desired result, but this was too long for a comment. The label format for subfigures is set to `simple` (just the counter with no parenthesis); `\thesubfigure` is redefined to include the parenthesis and then `\p@subfigure` (the prefix used when cross-referencing subfigures) is redefined to be the representation for the `figure` counter followed by a non-breakable space:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\DeclareCaptionSubType[alph]{figure}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=simple,justification=centerlast}

\renewcommand\thesubfigure{\alph{subfigure})}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\p@subfigure{\thefigure~}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test chapter}

A reference to the figure:~\ref{fig:test}

A reference to the first subfigure:~\ref{sfig:testa}

A subreference to the first subfigure:~\subref{sfig:testa}

A reference to the second subfigure:~\ref{sfig:testb}

A subreference to the second subfigure:~\subref{sfig:testb}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
\begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[height=4cm]{example-image-a}
\caption{a subfigure}
\label{sfig:testa}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[height=4cm]{example-image-b}
\caption{another subfigure}
\label{sfig:testb}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{a figure with two subfigures}
\label{fig:test}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Much to my pleasure it works with `floatrow` as well.

Comment: thank you! Is there a way to automatically turn off `hyperref` from linking `\subref` ?

Comment: `\subref*{}` will not link, but you HAVE to instal hyperref or it will crash.

Answer (score 0):

This solution introduces `\sublabel` to reformat `\ref` by redefining `\@currentlabel`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{floatrow}%

%\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
%\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{float}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\sublabel}[1]{\protected@edef\@currentlabel{\thefigure(\thesubfigure)}\label{#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\noindent
Citation test - Figure \ref{figure}

\noindent
\ref{figure_1} and \subref{figure_1}\newline
\captionsetup{subrefformat=parens}%
\ref{figure_2} and \subref{figure_2}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
\centering
    \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}            
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
            \caption{Caption 1}

            \sublabel{figure_1}
    \end{subfigure}%
    %\qquad
     %add desired spacing between images, e. g. ~, \quad, \qquad etc.
      %(or a blank line to force the subfigure onto a new line)
    \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
            \caption{Caption 2}

            \sublabel{figure_2}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Caption of the figure}\label{figure}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]