# Where does cleveref construct its label?

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref

I am trying to adjust the rendering of a reference to a nested enum.
Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt,openany]{memoir}

\usepackage{cleveref}

\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\arabic{enumi}}
\renewcommand{\theenumii}{\arabic{enumii}}
\renewcommand{\theenumiii}{\arabic{enumiii}}

\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\arabic{enumi}}
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\arabic{enumii}}
\renewcommand{\labelenumiii}{\arabic{enumiii}}

\crefformat{enumi}{#2#1#3}
\crefformat{enumii}{#2#1#3}
\crefformat{enumiii}{#2#1#3}

\labelcrefformat{enumi}{#2#1#3}
\labelcrefformat{enumii}{#2#1#3}
\labelcrefformat{enumiii}{#2#1#3}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
 \item\label{first} First level
 \begin{enumerate}
  \item\label{second} Second level
  \begin{enumerate}
   \item\label{third} Third level
  \end{enumerate}  
 \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

First level ref: \cref{first}.

% Expected result: 1
Second level ref: \cref{second}.

% Expected result: 1
Third level ref: \cref{third}.

\end{document}
```

As you can see, I did everything I could, but I still couldn't reach whatever place in which `cleveref` "cooks" the label:

[image: Result]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue you describe is *not* related to the `cleveref` package. It would occur every bit as much if you used `\ref` instead of `\cref`. Being able to "reach whatever place in which `cleveref` 'cooks' the label" would be of absolutely no use here.

What's going on, then? For each counter variable (say, `mycounter`) defined via a `\newcounter` instruction, LaTeX automatically creates an associated macro (called `\p@mycounter`) that's used to create a "prefix" when creating a cross-references to that counter; the *full* cross-reference number is a combination of the outputs of `\p@mycounter` and `\themycounter` macros.

What exactly these prefix macros are supposed to do is a choice that's left to the document class designer; by default, these prefix macros usually do nothing. However, the prefix macros `\p@enumii` and `\p@enumiii` (as well as `\p@enumiv`) are *not empty* when one uses the `memoir` document class: they execute `\theenumi` and `\theenumi(\theenumii)`, respectively. That's what you have (re-)discovered.

If you want to reset these two prefix macros so that they "do nothing", you should provide the following code in the preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\p@enumii{}
\renewcommand\p@enumiii{}
\makeatother
```

(The `\makeatletter` directive changes the category code of the `@` character to "letter"; without it, macros whose names contain one or more `@` characters could not be modified via `\renewcommand`. The `\makeatother` directive restores the default category code of `@`, *viz.*, "other".)

Comment: Domo arigato OTL